# Make scroll without fade in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi i want edit this jquery code and make scrol sticky without fade in or fade out.

When the frins help me in this site i improved my code but i still have problem

> 1) When i scroll to top the menu start from -100px to 0px
>
> 2) The sticky menu still has fade

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $menu = $("#menuF");

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $menu.hasClass("default")) {

                $menu.removeClass("default")
                    .addClass("fixed transbg")
                    .fadeIn('fast');

        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 100 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {

               $menu.removeClass("fixed transbg")
                    .addClass("default")
                    .fadeIn('fast');

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Where i must write my code improve ?

Comment: You should post what you tried.

Comment: please do not score minus. i am beginner in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $menu = $("#menuF");

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $menu.hasClass("default")) {
            $(this).removeClass("default")
                .addClass("fixed transbg")
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 100 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
            $(this).removeClass("fixed transbg")
                .addClass("default")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I put
$menu.removeClass("default")
 instead
$(this).removeClass("default")
That was better and work but i still have problems

Comment: I cleared   .fadeIn('fast');  but still when i scroll the menu it fades

Comment: Put your code example include HTML and CSS in jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/     and describe exactly what the problem

Comment: It complicated. this is my website: www.darbarg.com in this website i want remove fadein and fadeout wen user scroles

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'show()' and 'hide()' instead of 'fadeIn()' and 'fadeOut()'

http://api.jquery.com/show/ 
http://api.jquery.com/hide/